# How to preload QDialog before it is shown?

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

I have a QT application, which creates a dialog which has a bunch of tab pages, which each have a lot of Widgets.

I know there isn't going to be a way to get around how long it takes to load the widgets in as there are quite a few.

I've thought about after the main window being initialized, if there is something I can do to load the dialog in the background, so when show is clicked it is a faster experience.

Are there any techniques to preload dialogs, perhaps after the main window has loaded? When I say preload, I mean the 'new QDialog(..)...' process. That seems to be where the latency is as then that constructor begins laying out all the components and so on. the .show() isn't the issue as that runs instantly.

```
QCustomDialog * customDialog = new QCustomDialog(); // the latency
customDialog->show(); //not the latency

class QCustomDialog {
  QCustomDialog::QCustomDialog() {
   //creation of many nesscary widgets and added to the dialog
   QLabel * lab = new QLabel("Label 1");
  ...
 };

 
};
```

Comment: Are you running a release build? Perhaps you are running a debug build that has all optimizations off and includes heap corruption detection so its slow.

Comment: sometimes is not the dialog but the way you are using the widgets... specially those that must be "filled" in constructor...

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I create all the widgets off a call to the constructor but I'm not really sure what you mean haha

Comment: @drescherjm yeah its a release build unfortunately

Comment: Maybe redesign so you don't create the individual tab pages until someone clicks on the tab.

Comment: @StefanMonov not sure. I'm just trying to figure this out :(. Dosen't seem that I can load in UI elements off of the GUI thread

Comment: @drescherjm yeah its sounding like thats what I'm gonna have to do

Comment: @user6528273 sorry, added it at the end.. I guess I just got lost in my thoughts

Comment: right.. in this case I mean preloading the 'creation' of the QDialog object. That is where the latency is, the show isn't the issue. Creating the QDialog because of all the UI components created in it takes on average over a second to run. I'll edit the question

Comment: @user6528273 please reopen my question.. thanks

Comment: Show the method where you create the dialog and the place where this method is called.

Comment: @joequest1 Your question is not clear (so I think it should not be reopened yet), doing `new QDialog(..)` is not very time consuming so I think you have another part of the code that generates the problem.

Comment: its just a new call on the dialog class and then a show after that. That gets triggered by a button. Whatever, you seem determined to police my question

Comment: @user6528273 thanks for making everything harder. thanks.

Comment: @joequest1 1) Do not give importance to the DVs, those votes only show (at the time I wrote this comment) that at least 2 users with the privilege of voting did not like your question, and there are another 2 with the same conditions as if they taste. I don't see people asking: why did they give me a UV? Since it does not interest the votes in particular but the accumulated ones, so in general your post neither we like nor dislike.

Comment: @joequest1 2) Focus on your question, the creation of a QDialog does not consume appreciable time so probably the other part of your code that you do not indicate is causing the problems, IMHO you have an XY problem. 3) We are few users that with our appreciations we are trying to help you since we want you to clarify your question, if your question would not interest us, we would just continue on our way and would not have any help.

Comment: @eyllanesc I've elaborated on the question, the core issue is the large amount of widgets that get loaded in the constructor of the Dialog class. This seems to be unavoidable latency. Creating labels, comboboxes, text fields etc. There really isn't much to show from that. The issue is creating all those seem to take time. The solution I've been searching for is if there is a way to call that dialog class in parallel before hand, or load it in the background from the main window. By load I mean create it, so then a simple show command would be quick

Comment: @joequest1 I have created widgets with many elements and I have not observed that problem. How many widgets have you created?

Comment: @user6528273 I added code to the question.

Comment: @eyllanesc in this case its probably 100 widgets or so. takes just under a 1 second to do. which I guess is fine, I'm more trying to figure out how to create the 'in the background' dialog (without tying up the main window thread)

Comment: @joequest1 creating 100 widgets is nothing, you shouldn't have a problem. I suspect that the problem is another. Have you accurately measured the creation time of those widgets? Anyway the code you provide is not [mre] so I will go my way.

Comment: I still don't see the method, to which the creation code belongs, neighter where it is called. As @eyllanesc says, make a `mre`, as it indeed seems like a XY-problem. Meanwhile you might as well try to move `QCustomDialog * customDialog = new QCustomDialog();` out of wherever it is, and put it in the constructor of your `MainWindow`. Do this for a test only, as I personlally strongly discrourage doing so in practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to let the user know the application is starting, and it takes a few seconds before the main window loads, you could use [QSplashScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html).

This allows you to display an image while the main window loads. If the application takes more than a few seconds, and it makes sense for your application, you can also use `QSplashScreen::message()` to display messages as different parts of the app are loading.